# cloudinaryJsLib.Cloudinary is not a constructor Angular 6 Cloudinary

Tags: angular, service, cloudinary

i try to integrate Cloudinary in my Angular version 6.0.5 project but I get this error:

> cloudinaryJsLib.Cloudinary is not a constructor

in cloudinary.service.js on line 66

here my app.module.ts

```
...

import { Cloudinary as CloudinaryCore } from 'cloudinary-core';
import { CloudinaryConfiguration, CloudinaryModule } from '@cloudinary/angular-5.x';
import { Cloudinary } from '@cloudinary/angular-5.x/src/cloudinary.service';

export const cloudinary = { Cloudinary: CloudinaryCore };
export const config: CloudinaryConfiguration = { cloud_name: environment.CLOUDINARY_NAME,  upload_preset: environment.CLOUDINARY_PRESENT };


export function HttpLoaderFactory(httpClient: HttpClient) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(httpClient);
}

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        LoginComponent,
        SelRegionComponent,
        SelAreaComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        FileUploadModule,
        FormsModule,

        CloudinaryModule.forRoot(cloudinary, config),

        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
                deps: [HttpClient]
            }
        })
    ],
    providers: [TranslationSettingsService],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and here the code template:

```
<cl-image public-id="problem.images[0].public_id">
         <cl-transformation alt="A sample photo" className="Samples">
          </cl-transformation>
</cl-image>
```

Angular CLI: 6.0.8, Node: 8.11.2, Angular: 6.0.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the following samples for more information on integrating with Cloudinary- https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_angular/tree/master/samples/angular-cli-sample